# Intellij complains about must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method '$init$()' in 'Plugin'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create a custom plugin in Play Framework 2.1.1 in Java, but my IntellJ is complaining that I must implement the $init$ method (scala trail def)

[image]

The plugin works (for what is actually does at this stage), but the red compiler error seems wrong.

Comment: Just suppress this error for this class. If it works, then IntelliJ is wrong -- that's not unheard of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is an issue with the Scala plugin and the Play 2.0 support plugin.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5313

Comment: Both Play and Scala plugins have been updated today and now "play" nicely together.